# Swift, Web Service response in Json Instead of XML

Tags: xml, web-services, swift

I am receiving a response in JSON Instead of XML in swift.

### Below is my code

```
   var urlStr: String = "\<URL>?PROP_COUNT=10&USER_CODE&PRDL_CODE=BR_PT_OFF_AG"


    var url = NSURL(string: urlStr)

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
    request.URL = url
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    var xmlParse: NSString  = ""
    var data : NSData!

     request.setValue("application/xml", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
     request.setValue("application/xml", forHTTPHeaderField: "Acceept")


   // let dictionary = ["email": base64String, "userPwd": base64StringPwd] as NSDictionary
    let dictionary: NSDictionary = NSDictionary()
    var error: NSError?


    if let body = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(dictionary, options: nil, error: &error)
    {
        request.HTTPBody = body
    }
    else
    {
        println("JSON error: \(error)")
    }

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        (data, response, error) in
        let xmlParse=NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
          println("parser:Data \(xmlParse)")
        if data == nil {
            println("dataTaskWithRequest error: \(error)")
            return
        }

        var error: NSError?


     }
    task.resume()
```

I want to fetch response in XML.
Can some one tell me what i am doing wrong?
Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Not sure if this is the source of the error, but you have a typo: `"Acceept"` should be `"Accept"`

Comment: thanks @Eric D..I have missed this one...it helps to resolve my issue

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the data format is set up at the service's side. If you use an external service you have to check if they provide an XML format, which is ussualy a parameter in the URL string. If you made the service yourself then you should alter the format.